# vue.js 'document.getElementById' shorthand

Tags: jquery, getelementbyid, vue.js

Does vue.js have a shorthand for `document.getElementById('#id')` like JQuery's `$('#id')`?

If so, where is the reference for this in the docs so I can locate other information?

Answer (score 99):

Theres no shorthand way in vue 2.

Jeff's method seems already deprecated in vue 2.

Heres another way u can achieve your goal.

```js
 var app = new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    methods: {    
        showMyDiv() {
           console.log(this.$refs.myDiv);
        }
    }
    
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id='app'>
   <div id="myDiv" ref="myDiv"></div>
   <button v-on:click="showMyDiv" >Show My Div</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I tired this on a from input once.  I think id="something" and rel="something" are both needed for it to work, and a little extra work is needed to pull the value of the input.  There's probably a better way to do this, however this will work when you are getting object object back and you require the input value.

let searchTerm = this.$refs["search_input"].$el.value;
 alert(searchTerm);

Comment: @WilliamHammock : when referring to the element by `ref` there is NO need in `id`.

Answer (score 17):

You can use the directive `v-el` to save an element and then use it later.

https://vuejs.org/api/#vm-els

```
<div v-el:my-div></div>
<!-- this.$els.myDiv --->
```

**Edit**: This is [deprecated in Vue 2](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#v-el-and-v-ref-replaced), see 胡亚雄 answer

Comment: This is deprecated, don't use in vuejs 2

Comment: Read https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2873 for details on what is deprecated and what's not

Answer (score 7):

you can find your answer in the combination of these two pages in  the [**API**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/):

- **[REF](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref)**

> ref is used to register a reference to an element or a child
> component. The reference will be registered under the parent
> component’s $refs object. If used on a plain DOM element, the
> reference will be that element

- **[vm.$refs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-refs)**

> An object that holds child components that have ref registered.

Answer (score 7):

Try not to do DOM manipulation by referring the DOM directly, it will have lot of performance issue, also event handling becomes more tricky when we try to access DOM directly, instead use data and directives to manipulate the DOM.

This will give you more control over the manipulation, also you will be able to manage functionalities in the modular format.

Comment: Not always an option. See: HTML5 Canvas.

Answer (score 6):

If you're attempting to get an element you can use `Vue.util.query` which is really just a wrapper around `document.querySelector` but at 14 characters vs 22 characters (respectively) it is technically shorter. It also has some error handling in case the element you're searching for doesn't exist.

There isn't any official documentation on `Vue.util`, but this is the entire source of the function:

```
function query(el) {
  if (typeof el === 'string') {
    var selector = el;
    el = document.querySelector(el);
    if (!el) {
      ({}).NODE_ENV !== 'production' && warn('Cannot find element: ' + selector);
    }
  }
  return el;
}
```

Repo link: [Vue.util.query](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/util/dom.js#L14)

Answer (score 1):

Update for Vue v3. There is now a feature called a Template Ref ([docs link](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#accessing-the-refs)). With the ref created in the script section, adding the ref property to the element that you want to access will connect the two.

```
<script setup>
  import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'

  // declare a ref to hold the element reference
  // the name must match template ref value
  const input = ref(null)

  onMounted(() => {
    input.value.focus()
  })
</script>

<template>
  <input ref="input" />
</template>
```