# vuejs getelementbyid django

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36970062/vue-js-document-getelementbyid-shorthand)
, the way to get html element with `Vue.js` is by using [$ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref).

In my Django Form html, I want to get

```
<input type="hidden" name="form-TOTAL_FORMS" value="2" id="id_form-TOTAL_FORMS" />
```

with something like `$('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val()`.

Is there a solution with Vue.js ?

In addition, `console.log(this.$ref);` in `mounted` of my View instance outputs `undefined`.

Comment: Normally, you should use v-model for this case. But if you don't want that, you can use `this.$el.querySelector('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').value` or, you should add ref attribute to your html element. Then you can access it via `this.$refs`.

Comment: Thank you ! I can now access the `value` attribute in my input form. Anyway, `this.$ref` is good too even if sometimes I can't add a `ref` attribute.