# How to test Vue.js plugin function that return a document element?

Tags: vue.js, testing, plugins, mixins

I create a simple Vue.js plugin, and want to test that with npm and jest.
One function should return a document element by id, but it return always `null`.
Why is that and how can i fix it?

```
// plugintest.js

const PluginTest = {
    install(Vue, options) {
        Vue.mixin({
            methods: {
                getBool: function() { return true; },
                getElem: function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }
            }
        });
    }
}

export default PluginTest;
```

```
//plugintest.spec.js

let Vue = require('vue/dist/vue')
import PluginTest from './plugintest.js';

Vue.use(PluginTest);

describe("plugintest.js", () => {

    test('test functions', () => {
        const wrapper = new Vue({
            template: '<div id="div1">Hello, World!</div>' }).$mount();

        expect(wrapper.getBool()).toBe(true);
        expect(wrapper.getElem('div1')).not.toBe(null); // FAIL!!!
    });
});
```

Error message:

```
expect(received).not.toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: not null

      19 |
      20 |         expect(wrapper.getBool()).toBe(true);
    > 21 |         expect(wrapper.getElem('div1')).not.toBe(null);
         |                                       ^
      22 |     });
      23 | });
      24 |

      at Object.toBe (plugintest.spec.js:21:39)
```

`console.log(wrapper.$el)` output:

```
HTMLDivElement {
        __vue__:
         Vue {
           _uid: 1,
           _isVue: true,
           '$options':
            { components: {},
              directives: {},
              filters: {},
              _base: [Object],
              methods: [Object],
              template: '<div id="div1">Hello, World!</div>',
              render: [Function: anonymous],
              staticRenderFns: [] },
           _renderProxy:
            Vue {
              _uid: 1,
              _isVue: true,
              '$options': [Object],
              _renderProxy: [Circular],
              _self: [Circular],
              '$parent': undefined,
              '$root': [Circular],
              '$children': [],
              '$refs': {},
              _watcher: [Object],
              _inactive: null,
              _directInactive: false,
              _isMounted: true,
              _isDestroyed: false,
              _isBeingDestroyed: false,
              _events: {},
              _hasHookEvent: false,
              _vnode: [Object],
              _staticTrees: null,
              '$vnode': undefined,
              '$slots': {},
              '$scopedSlots': {},
              _c: [Function],
              '$createElement': [Function],
              '$attrs': [Getter/Setter],
              '$listeners': [Getter/Setter],
              _watchers: [Object],
              getBool: [Function: bound getBool],
              getElem: [Function: bound getElem],
              _data: {},
              '$el': [Circular] },
           _self: [Circular],
           '$parent': undefined,
           '$root': [Circular],
           '$children': [],
           '$refs': {},
           _watcher:
            Watcher {
              vm: [Circular],
              deep: false,
              user: false,
              lazy: false,
              sync: false,
              before: [Function: before],
              cb: [Function: noop],
              id: 2,
              active: true,
              dirty: false,
              deps: [],
              newDeps: [],
              depIds: Set {},
              newDepIds: Set {},
              expression: 'function () {\n        vm._update(vm._render(), hydrating);\n      }',
              getter: [Function: updateComponent],
              value: undefined },
           _inactive: null,
           _directInactive: false,
           _isMounted: true,
           _isDestroyed: false,
           _isBeingDestroyed: false,
           _events: {},
           _hasHookEvent: false,
           _vnode:
            VNode {
              tag: 'div',
              data: [Object],
              children: [Object],
              text: undefined,
              elm: [Circular],
              ns: undefined,
              context: [Circular],
              fnContext: undefined,
              fnOptions: undefined,
              fnScopeId: undefined,
              key: undefined,
              componentOptions: undefined,
              componentInstance: undefined,
              parent: undefined,
              raw: false,
              isStatic: false,
              isRootInsert: true,
              isComment: false,
              isCloned: false,
              isOnce: false,
              asyncFactory: undefined,
              asyncMeta: undefined,
              isAsyncPlaceholder: false },
           _staticTrees: null,
           '$vnode': undefined,
           '$slots': {},
           '$scopedSlots': {},
           _c: [Function],
           '$createElement': [Function],
           '$attrs': [Getter/Setter],
           '$listeners': [Getter/Setter],
           _watchers: [ [Object] ],
           getBool: [Function: bound getBool],
           getElem: [Function: bound getElem],
           _data: {},
           '$el': [Circular] } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `vm.$el`.

`expect(wrapper.$el).not.toBe(null);`

> The root DOM element that the Vue instance is managing.

[Reference](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-el)

**NOTICE**

If you want to access another elements, your code could look something like this:

`expect(wrapper.$el.querySelector("div")).not.toBe(null);`

Another option is to use **VueTestUtils's** `find` mthod: https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/find.html#find

**Using VueTestUtils**

Try using `attachToDocument` option.
[Reference](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#attachtodocument)

```
import { mount, createLocalVue } from "@vue/test-utils";

import PluginTest from "./plugintest.js";

const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use(PluginTest);

it("plugintest.js", () => {
  const component = {
    template: "<div id="div1">Hello, World!</div>"
  }
    
  const wrapper = mount(component, {
    localVue,
    attachToDocument: true
  });
 
  expect(wrapper.vm.getElem("div1")).not.toBe(null);
});
```

Comment: `expect(wrapper.$el).not.toBe(null);` passed. `expect(wrapper.$el.querySelector("div")).not.toBe(null);` failed. `expect(wrapper.$el.querySelector("#div1")).not.toBe(null);` failed, too. I add the output from `wrapper.$el` to my question.

Comment: You have only one root element (`<div id="div1"></div>`), and link to it is returned in `vm.$el`, there **is no other** `div` elements in this template `<div id="div1">Hello, World!</div>`.

Comment: Oh i see. But to come back to my question: The point is that i cannot test a function like `getElem(id)`? Because when I use the plugin in a project the function work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'r missing the parameter for `getElem()`, try it like:

```
expect(wrapper.getElem('div1')).not.toBe(null);
```

Comment: Yes i miss it in the example. Sorry. But thats not the problem.

Comment: Have a look at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36970062/vue-js-document-getelementbyid-shorthand

Comment: I add `getRefElem: function(ref) { return this.$refs[ref]; }` to plugintest.js, modify to template string to `<div ref="refDiv">Hello, again!</div>` and add `console.log(wrapper.getRefElem('refDiv'));` to plugintest.spec.js. It return now a empty HTMLDivElement